# SFDX Automatic push to server, automatically enabled?

Tags: salesforcedx

I used to have to add the line in the settings.json

> salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled”: true

I had to do this every time I created a new project to ensure that when I saved a class it pushed to the sandbox I was working in. Now it seems that I don't have to as I forgot to add it on a project, saved a class, and it pushed to Salesforce without the above line in the settings.

Was this a change that happened recently? I cannot find any documentation about it that's recent.

Comment: Please check that the option is enabled or disabled Select File > Preferences > Settings (Windows or Linux)
Under Salesforce Feature Previews, select Push-or-deploy-on-save: Enabled or disabled